# How to join two const that have json "const = [ { } ]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

This is the original code and i want to join to sections.

```
const sections = 
[
                                            
    {
        title: section1_title,
            rows: [{ title: section1_option01, rowId: "sec1_option01", description: section1_option01_description }]
    
    }

]
```

How i can do that

```
const sections1 = 
[
                                            
    {
        title: section1_title,
            rows: [{ title: section1_option01, rowId: "sec1_option01", description: section1_option01_description }]
    
    }

]
```

```
const sections2 = 
[
                                            
    {
        title: section2_title,
            rows: [{ title: section2_option01, rowId: "sec2_option01", description: section2_option01_description }]
    
    }

]
```

and finally

```
const joinsection = sections1 + sections2 (Something like this)
```

I tried to combine the two in this way but without success.

Comment: Instead of having `sections1`, `sections2`, etc. you should just use an array: `[{<section1 here>}, {<section2 here>}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the spread operator [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
const joinsection = [...sections1, ...sections2];
```